# c# How to break an inner loop and get outer loop to continue with the exact element that caused the inner loop to break?

Tags: c#

How do I break an inner loop and tell the outer loop to continue with the exact element that caused the the inner loop to break?

I don't want the outer loop to go through all elemts of an array again.

Example:

```
int[] Arr1 = new int[4] { 100, 200, 300, 400 };

int[] Arr2 = new int[3] { 80, 600, 700 };



            bool continueLoop = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < Arr2.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Arr1.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Arr2[j] < 0) // break condition met?
                    {
                        continueLoop = true; // set a flag to tell the outer loop to continue
                        break;
                    }

                    Arr2[j] = Arr2[j] - Arr1[i];
                    textBox1.Text += Arr2[j].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

                }
                if (continueLoop) // check if inner loop set continue
                   continue;

            }
```

That is the Output:

```
-20  
500  
300  
0  
-400  
600  
400  
100  
-300
```

Desired Output:

```
80-100 = -20  
600-20 = 580  
580-200 = 380  
380-300 = 80  
80-400 = -320  
700-320 = 380
```

Comment: Show an example of your loops and what you've tried. The answer below is taking a guess at what you mean

Comment: That is what a simple break does, isn't it?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 original post is updated now :)

Comment: Your question still does not make much sense. The outer  loop will continue with or without the if(continueLoop) check since it's the last statement of the loop. Is there more after it you're trying to skip?

Comment: I noticed that this part doesnt make sense. I was just trying to test some things to somehow get to the desired output...do you know how i can get to those values?

Answer (score -1):

Usually, this would be done like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i < array.Lenght; i++)
{
    while(*condition*)
    {
        i++
    }
    //Continue with i in new location
}
```